# JWT requesting token even on register and login

Tags: java, spring-boot, jwt

i would like to ask how to remove jwt token filter attaching on every request. I actually need it on every request but not on login or register.I tried with WebSecurityConfig but it didn't worked, i searched google but the solutions didn't help me either, so i am asking here i will paste some of the code so you can check it out and give me suggestions

i get

```
JWT Token does not begin with Bearer string
```

every time i made a request from postman to login or register

WebSecurityConfig

```
 @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                    .csrf().disable()
                    // make sure we use stateless session; session won't be used to store user's state.
                    .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                    .and()
                    // authorization requests config
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    // allow all who are accessing "auth" service
                    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/login").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/register").permitAll()
                    // must be an admin if trying to access admin area (authentication is also required here)
                    .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasAuthority("ADMIN")
                    //for other uris
                    //   .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/v1/**").hasRole("USER")
                    // Any other request must be authenticated
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                    .and()
                    // handle an authorized attempts
                    .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint((req, rsp, e) -> rsp.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED))
                    .and()
                    // Add a filter to validate the tokens with every request
                    .addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
```

JwtRequestFilter

```
   @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        final String requestTokenHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");

        String username = null;
        String jwtToken = null;
        if(requestTokenHeader != null && requestTokenHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")){
            jwtToken = requestTokenHeader.substring(7);

            try {
                username = jwtTokenUtil.getUsernameFromToken(jwtToken);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                logger.error("Unable to get JWT Token");
            } catch (ExpiredJwtException e) {
                logger.info("JWT Token has expired");
            }
        } else {
            logger.warn("JWT Token does not begin with Bearer string");
        }

        if(username != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() != null) {
            UserDetails userDetails = this.jwtUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);

            if(jwtTokenUtil.validateToken(jwtToken, userDetails)) {
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
                usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));

                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);
            }
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint

```
    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException, ServletException {
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Unauthorized");
    }
```

AuthRest

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<?> login(@RequestBody JwtRequest authenticationRequest) throws Exception {
        authenticate(authenticationRequest.getUsername(), authenticationRequest.getPassword());

        final UserDetails userDetails = this.jwtUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(authenticationRequest.getUsername());
        final String token = jwtToken.generateToken(userDetails);

        return ResponseEntity.ok(new JwtResponse(token));
    }

    private void authenticate(String username, String password) throws Exception {
        try {
            authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password));
        } catch (DisabledException e) {
            throw new Exception("USER_DISABLED", e);
        } catch (BadCredentialsException e) {
            throw new Exception("INVALID_CREDENTIALS", e);
        }
    }
```

UserRest

```
@PostMapping(value = "/register")
    public ResponseEntity<?> register(@RequestBody UserDto userDto) {
        String username = userDto.getEmail();
        User user = new User();

        if(userRepo.existsByEmail(username)){
            return new ResponseEntity<>(new ApiResponse(false, "Email already exists!"), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }

        user.setEmail(userDto.getEmail());
        user.setFullName(userDto.getFullName());
        user.setPassword(new BCryptPasswordEncoder().encode(userDto.getPassword()));

        User result = userRepo.save(user);

        URI location = ServletUriComponentsBuilder
                .fromCurrentContextPath().path("/users/{username}")
                .buildAndExpand(result.getEmail()).toUri();

        return ResponseEntity.created(location).body(new ApiResponse(true, "User registered successfully"));
    }
```